# How can I call the media player when I receive a message in Android?

Tags: android

I want to play a sound when I receive a message. I have a BroadcastReceiver, in which I call a function from another avtivity called play which plays a sound or music. My code look like this:

#### In my main activity

My Play activity:

```
public class PlayActivity extends Activity
{
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public void play() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gotye);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

My broadcast receiver looks like:

```
package org.secure.sms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
    public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MainActivity Play;

    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        // Get SMS map from Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String messages = "";

        if ( extras != null )
        {
            // Get received SMS array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

            // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to incoming folder
            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

            for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
            {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

                String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

                messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";
                messages += body + "\n";

                putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
            }

            // Display SMS message
            Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            Play.play();
        }
    }
```

I get an error message saying app unfortunately failed. I can see the toast messages, but the app is not playing the music.

Comment: Can you please post your stack trade / error log?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you initailized PlayActivity somewhere else, your Play is null. Perhaps you can create and play the music directly inside your Broadcast Receiver?

I think you may have to use a different input approach when using raw types. Using file paths and URIs would be easier but here is some sample code on Raw files.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.yourthinghere);
mp.setDataSource(afd.getDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
afd.close():
```

Comment: I tried to play the music from the Broadcast receiver like shown below :but an gettin some error :
 mediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments SMSReceiver 
The code i added is

            
            // Display SMS message
            Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gotye);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.start();

Comment: I tried 
mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(SMSReceiver.this, R.raw.gotye);
But then also m getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using `Play.play()` whereas the class name is PlayActivity. Also, your play method must be static if you are using <clasname>.<methodname>();

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. I have used PlayActivity.play();